# How to delay el.classList.remove?

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay

If you see an image when scrolling, it is set to be an animation.
If I can't see the image, I'll let them return to their original state, but I'd like to give them a "five-second" delay, not "immediately."
I tried to put delay, but it failed. Is there anyone who can help?
[This is an example.](https://jsfiddle.net/jwpg018241/dna7Lgqr/7/)

```
window.onload = function () {
            const targets = document.querySelectorAll('[data-observer]')
            const images = document.querySelectorAll('[data-img]')
            const options = {
                rootMargin: '0px',
                threshold: 1.0
            }
            const addClass = (el) => {
                if (!el.classList.contains('is-visible')) {
                    el.classList.add('is-visible')
                }
            }
            const removeClass = (el) => {
                if (el.classList.contains('is-visible')) {
                    el.classList.remove('is-visible')
                }
            }




            const doThings = (entries, observer) => {
                entries.forEach(entry => {
                    if (entry.isIntersecting) {
                        addClass(entry.target)
                    } else {
                        removeClass(entry.target)
                    }
                })
            }
            const observer = new IntersectionObserver(doThings, options)
            const observer2 = new IntersectionObserver(doThings, {
                ... options,
                threshold: 0.4
            })
            targets.forEach(target => {
                observer.observe(target)
            })
            images.forEach(target => {
                observer2.observe(target)
            })
        }
```

Comment: JavaScript **is not** Java, please edit the tags and add a *[minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)*. Btw to make a delay in javascript just use *[`setTimeout` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout)*

Comment: so use setTimeout

Comment: FYI: http://javascriptisnotjava.com/

Comment: By the way, `classList.add` and `classList.remove` don't throw errors if the class to act on are already in or are not in the list, it just doesn't add or remove the class, so there's no need for the `contains` checks...

Comment: It's been solved. Thank you !
https://jsfiddle.net/jwpg018241/dna7Lgqr/17/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

### setTimeout

The global `setTimeout()` method sets a timer which executes a function or specified piece of code once the timer expires. (From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout))

### Usage

```
setTimeout(function, delay);
```

Better explained [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setTimeout).

Answer (score 0):

Bro,use Thread.sleep() for delay.